# Angular2- RC6 Custom Form Controls Not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have updated my Angular2 RC5 application to RC6. I have developed some custom form controls based on [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html) tutorial from Thoughtram.

Everything was working until RC5, however after update the validation is not working anymore after a bit of investigation I found that the control's value is not reflected in the associated model.

You can find the original plunker from Thoughtram's tutorial [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bLXWXn).

To reproduce the issue update the version information in `systemjs.config.js` file from

```
var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.5'; 
var routerVer = '@3.0.0-rc.1'; 
var formsVer = '@0.3.0'; 
var routerDeprecatedVer = '@2.0.0-rc.2';
```

to

```
var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.6'; 
var routerVer = '@3.0.0-rc.2'; 
var formsVer = '@2.0.0-rc.6';
```

After the version update you will see that the control value is not updated and due to this the validation does not work.

However, if I update the angular version to `@2.0.0-rc.6` and keep the forms version intact i.e. `@0.3.0`, it works.

**UPDATE 1:** Code for the component is

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';


export function createCounterRangeValidator(maxValue, minValue) {
  return (c: FormControl) => {
    let err = {
      rangeError: {
        given: c.value,
        max: maxValue || 10,
        min: minValue || 0
      }
    };

  return (c.value > +maxValue || c.value < +minValue) ? err: null;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'counter-input',
  template: `
    <button (click)="increase()">+</button> {{counterValue}} <button (click)="decrease()">-</button>
  `,
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CounterInputComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CounterInputComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class CounterInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {

  propagateChange:any = () => {};
  validateFn:any = () => {};

  @Input('counterValue') _counterValue = 0;
  @Input() counterRangeMax;
  @Input() counterRangeMin;

  get counterValue() {
    return this._counterValue;
  }

  set counterValue(val) {
    this._counterValue = val;
    this.propagateChange(val);
  }

  ngOnChanges(inputs) {
    if (inputs.counterRangeMax || inputs.counterRangeMin) {
      this.validateFn = createCounterRangeValidator(this.counterRangeMax, this.counterRangeMin);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.counterValue = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  increase() {
    this.counterValue++;
  }

  decrease() {
    this.counterValue--;
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validateFn(c);
  }
}
```

Main module looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CounterInputComponent } from './counter-input.component.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, CounterInputComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and I am using the component in my app.component like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { createCounterRangeValidator } from './counter-input.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Inside Form</h2>
    <div>
      <label>Change min value:</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="minValue">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Change max value:</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="maxValue">
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <p>Control value: {{form.controls.counter.value}}</p>
      <p>Min Value: {{minValue}}</p>
      <p>Max Value: {{maxValue}}</p>
      <p>Form Value:</p>
      <pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>

      <counter-input
        formControlName="counter"
        [counterRangeMax]="maxValue"
        [counterRangeMin]="minValue"
        [counterValue]="50"
        ></counter-input>
    </form>

    <p *ngIf="!form.valid">Form is invalid!</p>


    <h2>Standalone</h2>
    <counter-input
      counterMinValue="0"
      counterMaxValue="3"
      [counterValue]="counterValue"></counter-input>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  form:FormGroup;
  counterValue = 3;
  minValue = 0;
  maxValue = 12;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      counter: this.counterValue
    });
  }

}
```

**Update 2**: I've reported this issue on Github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11479)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optional registerOnChange() function was introduced in RC.6 for validator directives and there already exists a function with same name in controlValueAccessor which caused a conflicts and registerOnChange in my component was invoked twice.

This has been  fixed under the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11492).

Suggested temporary workaround is

```
@Component({
  ...
  ...
})
export class CounterInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {

  isPropagate: boolean = false;

  /*Rest of the class implementation
  ...
  ...
  */

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    if (this.isPropagate) {
      return;
    }

    this.propagateChange = fn;
    this.isPropagate = true;
  }

  //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating your source.  I have a control that does essentially what you're doing here also:

This is the child component spinner:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'kg-spinner',
  templateUrl: './app/shared/numberSpinner/kgSpinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/shared/numberSpinner/kgSpinner.component.css']
})

export class KgSpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('startValue') curValue: number;
  @Input() range: number[];
  @Input() increment: number;
  @Input() spinName;
  @Input() precision: number;
  @Input() theme: string;

  @Output() onChanged = new EventEmitter<SpinnerReturn>();

  lowerLimit: number;
  upperLimit: number;
  name: string;
  curTheme: Theme;
  errorMessage: string;
  sr: SpinnerReturn;
  appPageHeaderDivStyle: {};
  unit: string = "(g)";

  constructor(private ts: ThemeService) {
    this.sr = new SpinnerReturn();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lowerLimit = this.range[0];
    this.upperLimit = this.range[1];
    this.appPageHeaderDivStyle = this.ts.getAppPageHeaderDivStyle();
    if(this.spinName === "carbGoal") {
      this.unit = "(g)";
    } else if (this.spinName === "proteinGoal") {
      this.unit = "(g)";
    } else {
      this.unit = "(%)";
    }
  }
```

The html:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-8 spinnerMargin">
                      <kg-spinner spinName="proteinGoal" [range]=[.6,1.2] [increment]=.1 [startValue]=.6 [precision]=1 (onChanged)="onChanged($event)"></kg-spinner>
                    </div>
```

The parent component onChanged:

```
  onChanged(sr: SpinnerReturn) {
        if (sr.spinName === "carbGoal") {
            (<FormControl>this.macroForm.controls['carbGoal']).setValue(sr.spinValue);
        } else if (sr.spinName === "proteinGoal") {
            (<FormControl>this.macroForm.controls['proteinGoal']).setValue(sr.spinValue);
        } else if (sr.spinName === "calorieDifference") {
            (<FormControl>this.macroForm.controls['calorieDifference']).setValue(sr.spinValue);
        }
```

This all works perfectly on RC6.  Hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: As you can see I am not using any deprecated thing in the source code provided. So its some other issue I believe.

Comment: There is a difference here. My component is a custom form control which can make a form valid/invalid based on the value. In your case you are writing a custom component. The problem I am facing only appears if you write a custom form control. The link to the custom form controls is http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Okay... but I don't see the differentiation between the two. I only allow valid values in the child component, so their output is always valid.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to solve my issue. But as I said earlier that my component is a form control which means you can put it inside a form and set builtin/custom Validators on it and If the validation will fail the form will become invalid. If you will read the link I sent in my earlier comment above, you will get the whole picture.

Comment: You're missing my point.  If you are implementing a spinner provide it valid ranges like I did in my sample.  I use this in a number of forms and it works perfectly.  I only allow it valid ranges for input and set a valid default.  Form always stays valid because these controls are always valid. I don't see the point in allowing users to enter non-valid data...

Comment: The plunker I posted in the source code above is an example. In my real application its a text box to take user inputs

Comment: See my "Update 2" in the question.